# StringTokenizer reads a " \n " at end of string

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

```
StringTokenizer Token1 = new StringTokenizer(file2," ");
    while(Token1.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String word = Token1.nextToken();
        if(word.equals(Query1)){
            x =1;
            System.out.println("help");
        }else if(word.equals(Query2)){
            y =1;
        }
```

This is my code, it splits the string fine but the last token always has a \n and when I try to compare the last token with a value it should be it fails.

[image]

Thank you .trim() work perfectly :) :)

Comment: 1) Please use Java naming conventions, that means having your local variable names start with a lower case letter. 2) Don't use `StringTokenizer`. Use [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try  this

```
StringTokenizer Token1 = new StringTokenizer(file2.trim(), " ");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringTokenizer Token1 = new StringTokenizer(file2.replace("\n", ""), " ");
```